# Validation and Display Information Inputted on Text Fields

Tags: javascript, validation

I think I got the validations right and the alert message displays the name and values correctly. But my problem is : the alert box keeps on showing the information even if the validation is incorrect. I want the system to ONLY display the information inputted IF the validations are all true.

Here's my HTMTL :

```
<font face = "Algerian" ><h2>We'd Like to Know More About You!</h2></font>
<form name="info">
Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" id = "inf" name = "name" placeholder="Enter a valid name">*</br></br>
Address: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" id = "inf" name = "address" placeholder="Enter a valid address"></br></br>
Email Address: &nbsp <input type="email" id = "inf" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address">*</br></br>
Phone Number: &nbsp <input type = "tel" id = "inf" name ="PN"  placeholder="Enter a valid phone number">*</br></br>
<hr/> 
</form>


<input type = "button" onClick = "displayInfo()" value ="Submit Info">
</form>
```

Here's my Javascript :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
///////////validations
function ValEntry(){
    var valid = true;

    if ( document.info.name.value== ""||document.info.address.value== ""||document.info.email.value== ""||document.info.PN.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please fill up the remaining text boxes" );
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

function checkemail(){
    var testresults1
    var str=document.info.email.value
    var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i

    if (filter.test(str))
    testresults1=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid email address!")
    testresults1=false
    }
return (testresults1)
}

function checkphone(){
    var testresults2
    var int = document.info.PN.value
    var filter2= /[1-9]/g;

    if (filter2.test(int))
    testresults2=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid phone number!")
    testresults2=false
}
return (testresults2)
}

function validate(){
    if (document.info.email.value)
    return checkemail()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}

function validate2(){
    if (document.info.PN.value)
    return checkphone()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}



function FinalVal(){
ValEntry();
validate();
validate2();

}



function displayInfo(){
FinalVal();

    var fields=["name", "address", "email", "PN"];
    var fieldNames=["Name", "Address", "Email Address", "Phone Number"];
    var msg = "";

    for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
    msg += fieldNames[i] + ": " + document.info[ fields[i] ].value + "\n";

    alert(msg);
    return true;

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything with your validation return values. Try something like this:

```
function FinalVal(){
    return ValEntry() && validate() && validate2();
}

function displayInfo(){
    if (FinalVal()) {
        var fields=["name", "address", "email", "PN"];
        var fieldNames=["Name", "Address", "Email Address", "Phone Number"];
        var msg = "";

        for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
            msg += fieldNames[i] + ": " + document.info[ fields[i] ].value + "\n";

        alert(msg);
    }
    return true;
}
```